# Unable to location credentials using docker login with username = AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, authentication, amazon-ecr

I am running the following command

```
password = $(aws ecr get-login-password --region <myregion>)

docker login --username AWS --password $password <myid>.dkr.ecr.<myregion>.amazonaws.com
```

However it's returning the following error:

`Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".`

I was under the belief that the reason for the `AWS` login was so we didn't need credentials configured where it didn't make sense, like in my case, on the Bamboo build agent

Comment: Which command fails? The first one or the second with docker?

Comment: That’s from the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get-login-password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html) uses [GetAuthorizationToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_GetAuthorizationToken.html) AWS API action. So you need permissions to use that action. This requires IAM user or role, and subsequently, properly set [cli credentails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).